# Connectors: Relay to Heater

Tags: relay, connector

Simple project: Swap the on-off switch on a coffee-maker with a relay.

The relay is rated to be safe for wall power. The coffee-pot can take it, obviously. But the old crimp-on connectors that the coffee-pot used to connect to its on-off switch are far to big for the relay.

Ideally, I'd want to attach these wires to the relay directly, without introducing any new components, or adding any gaps between the already-nicely-insulated wires and the relay. Wouldn't want to create any opportunity for mains power to short!
[image: The relay, next to the wires that should get attached to it.]

How would you adapt these connectors to fit tight together?

Comment: Use a different relay if possible.  You can purchase relays that have Fast-On tabs that these cables will plug directly into.

Answer (score 1):

Solder wires onto the relay and use 1/4" insulated spade, male, crimp connectors on the ends. Push these into the existing female spades.

[image]

As Dwane has implied, you've bought the wrong relay. One with spade terminals would make the overall job more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Soldering wires onto the relay pins is a time-honored tradition for hacking *low-voltage* stuff.  But it is NOT RECOMMENDED for mains-voltage wiring!  It is actually prohibited by law or "code" in most civilized parts of the world.

I would find a relay socket or make a small PC board to provide a more suitable connection to those small, round pins.